# iOS 5 sdk issue with mutable arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

Hello I created a app on iOS 4.3.3 and than downloaded Xcode 4.2.1 and iOS sdk 5. It's a navigation-based application and it has a mutable array for the tableview but it won't create any strings for the array, so i added an object to array in the viewdidload but it is not working! So i added NSlog to the objects in my array and it says null! What should i do?

Here's the viewdidload:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.soldc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    self.color = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    appdelegate = (yard_sale_managerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]          delegate];
    appdelegate.object = self;
    NSMutableArray *loadi = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    self.items = loadi;
    self.sold = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    self.prices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add product" message:@"Enter your   product name and price." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Add" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",   nil];
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"name"];
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"price"];
    add = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    add.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    add.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    add.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    add.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    add2 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    add2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    add2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    add2.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    add2.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    NSLog(@"%i", [color count]);
    alert.tag=1;
    self.resa = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sale results" message:@"temple" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];
    self.prices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self pricesp]];
    self.sold = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self soldp]];
    self.soldc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self soldcp]];
    self.color = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self colorsp]];
    if ([self.soldc count]==0) {

    }
    //self.soldc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self soldcp]];
    self.color = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self colorsp]];
    [loadi release];
    self.resa.tag = 2;
    [self.items addObject:@"chair"];   
    [self.prices addObject:@"30"];
    [self.color addObject:@"0"];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.items);
}
```

If you need more information tell me!
This is the log:

```
2012-01-08 21:31:13.409 yard sale manager[1152:f803] 0
2012-01-08 21:31:13.411 yard sale manager[1152:f803] (null)
```

edit: read this its important!!!!!
a lot of people didn't notice that piece of code:
        [self.items addObject:@"chair"];
        [self.prices addObject:@"30"];
        [self.color addObject:@"0"];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.items);

Comment: You pretty clearly don't have the foggiest idea what you're doing.  What good does it do to update fields at the tail end of `viewDidLoad`?  And do you realize that `arrayWithContentsOfFile` can return nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
self.color = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

instantiates and assigns an empty array, you then do not add anything to it therefore the `0` count.

Then this line

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];
```

is probably the cause. Does `[self itemsp]` return a valid file path that points to a file that can be parsed into an `NSArray`.

There are also a lot of other issues with this code.

---

**Update**

This line

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];
```

must be returning `nil`.

Confirm by adding this line straight after it

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.items);
```

**How can I make this assumption**

The reason I am making this assumption is because you are getting `(null)`. When you call `addObject:` on `nil` you will get `nil` returned and it is a no-op. As you can see from this snippet

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = nil;

[myArray addObject:@"Test"];

NSLog(@"%@", myArray);

// => 2012-01-08 20:54:04.708 Untitled[4199:707] (null)
```

Just because `myArray` holds a pointer to an `NSMutableArray` it does not mean that you actually have one.

Therefore the last time you assign to `self.items` is in:

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];
```

which means `[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]]` is returning `nil`

Comment: i told you its only a part of the code and the path is:
    -(NSString*)itemsp{
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",   [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"items.plist"];
and i add stuff to color later and it won't add...
and it won't add my question is whats wrong with the arrays if you need more information just tell me what do you need and i will post it

Comment: That doesn't answer whether that is actually returning a valid path and if the file can be parsed into an `NSArray`

Comment: yes it does
                [self.items writeToFile:[self itemsp] atomically:YES];    its a backup system

Comment: The bundle is readonly so that will not write a file to disk.

Comment: but it works in the 4.3 simulator? leave that alone for a second why does it won't add the objects?

Comment: Well when the bundle is signed to put on a device it can not be changed without breaking the code signing therefore this is important.

Comment: The idea is you ask a question on this site for help. You don't seem interested in resolving the issue as you are just ignoring the advice. The last thing to get assigned to `self.items` is `[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];` therefore the ways that this is most likely to be nil is if the file does not exist or can not be parsed.

Comment: listen I'm here for help but the only problem is that i know that the file is there! before i updated i added object quit the app and when i entered it that line took place and replace all of the objects that were in that array before i closed it! you didn't understood my question... it won't add any objects only on iOS 5 simulator when i change it back to 4.3 it works perfectly...

Comment: I can't really help you anymore, you are incredibly defensive, you are not confirming what people are asking and you haven't really provided all relevant code.

Comment: listen at the bottom of the code theres [self.items addObject:@"chair"];   
    [self.prices addObject:@"30"];
    [self.color addObject:@"0"];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.items); so my question is why does that code won't add it^ and i don't understand what to change in the code by your answer and please just tell me what information do you need because i don't understand that either...

Comment: @user1014334 -- **You can't add objects to an array that doesn't exist!**  PYHOOYA!

Comment: @user1014334 self.items is NIL. NIL is NOT an array. You can not add something to NIL. Adding items to NIL will still result into a NOT array that is NIL. Your issue arises from the line `self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];`. Add an NSLog right below that line and print items -> voila!

Comment: @user1014334 **Try** some of the suggestions and report back  with the results. If there is more than one error first fix those you are aware of and then re-test for further errors.

Comment: ok guys i will do it. i can't do it right now i will be back home in few hours

Answer (score 0):

Given that `NSLog(@"%@",self.items);` prints `(null)` it follows that the `self.items` NSMutableArray is never created. The only way that could happen is if

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];
```

returns nil, that is does not read anything, probably because there is nothing at the path.

NSLog `self.items` right after the statement:

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self itemsp]];
```

If you are trying to write to the app bundle that won't work, you need to write a directory such as the sandboxed Documents directory.

Comment: that path exists i know it because when i change the simulator from 5 to 4.3 that enters some objects that i didn't added in the code that i saved into that file which is in the path. and lets say the path is incorrect than why that line don't work: [self.items addObject:@"chair"]; which is right above the NSlog won't add any objects?

Comment: What did you get from the NSLog I suggested **on the device**? Basically you are arguing that your code is correct and at the same time that it is not working, both arguments can't be right.

Comment: i still getting null and i only say that the code isn't compatible with ios5 and I'm not sure about it. got any more ideas?

Comment: @user1014334 your code is generally faulty and extremely optimistic. Read and learn a little about defensive programming. The fact that it works on iOS4 and fails on iOS5 does NOT deterministically mean that you found an incompatibility of iOS5. It may just as well mean that you were lucky before and now you face the truth: bad code.

Comment: listen im a beginner I'm aware that my code isn't amazing and great i will try what you suggest but not now I'm not at home...